# Negation support in python

Tags: python, syntax

I am reading a simple role based game that has the following code in it:

```
# Prompt user to buy some equipment.
purchase = raw_input('Would you like to buy some equipment? ')
while purchase ! ='done':
```

Now when I change the line `while purchase ! ='done'` to be while `purchase = not 'done'` as advised in many threads I have read in here I get an error:

```
File "game.py", line 143
    while purchase = not 'done':
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This has really made me confused about python syntax on matters of handling negation, which one should be used (! or not) and how should it be used.

Comment: `=` is assignment, use `==` instead. Also `not 'done'` is always `False`.

Comment: Please show the many threads (or even one) where this syntax is advised.

Comment: I think you are replacing `!` with `not` blindly. The not-equal comparison operator should be written as `!=` not `! =` and be regarded as one unit. Nothing is negated there, its just its an inequality comparison. On the other hand `if not purchase:` is a negation of purchase in a boolean context.

Comment: thanks dopstar your explanation makes much more sense, i should not have space between the two operators

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a single equals character is used *only* for assignments. And you can’t perform assignments within the while condition expression. For comparisons, you need to use two equals characters:

```
while purchase == not 'done':
```

Now, `not` is a boolean operator that inverts the following expression. So in your case `not 'done'` is evaluated. The operator enforces a boolean value, and since `'done'` is true-ish, it results in False:

```
>>> not 'done'
False
```

So, in the end, you are doing this:

```
while purchase == False:
```

The way you could have used `not` correctly here would be by putting it at the beginning of the comparison (which makes it wrap the whole expression):

```
while not purchase == 'done':
```

However, this is less clear than `while purchase != 'done'`, so you should really just stick to that.

Comment: The parentheses in your `not` example are completely unneccessary and IMO very bad style.

Comment: @l4mpi That was mostly to clarify that it applies to the whole expression, but I tried to express that with words now.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
while purchase != 'done':
```

Also note that changing it to

```
while purchase = 'done':
```

won't work because `=` is an assignment, you need `==` instead. And by saying `while purchase == not 'done'` your asking:

```
while purchase == False
```

which is not what you meant.